# Is it possible to get a Scala case class for an exisiting Java bean class?

Tags: java, scala, playframework

The short story of the question is in the title. There is some Java class e.g. [org.joda.time.Interval](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/apidocs/org/joda/time/Interval.html) and I'd like to (without rewriting it) make it a case class i.e. so that is has the `apply` and `unapply` methods.

Long story: I have a Scala-Play application and there I define a form that takes two intervals i.e.

```
import org.joda.time.Interval

case class MyParams(param1: String, interval1: Interval, interval2: Interval)
```

and then I attempt to define the nested mapping but `Interval` is a Java class and doesn't have `apply`/`unapply` and I'd rather not create my own copy.

```
val myForm = Form {
      mapping(
        "param1" -> nonEmptyText,
        "interval1" -> mapping(
          "start" -> jodaDate,
          "end" -> jodaDate,
        )(Interval.apply)(Interval.unapply), // <<<<<<<<<< Cannot resolve symbol ...
        "interval2" -> mapping(
          "start" -> jodaDate,
          "end" -> jodaDate,
        )(Interval.apply)(Interval.unapply) // <<<<<<<<<< Cannot resolve symbol ...
    )(MyParams.apply)(MyParams.unapply)
}
```

Of course, I could flatten the structure but doing so doesn't scale well design-wise plus there are existing JSON composite structures that will need the composition and I'd like to reuse the form to bind to both JSON requests and form submits.

**UPDATE** building on top of the accepted answer and taking syntactic sugar into account I did at the end:

```
object IntervalUtils {
  implicit object Interval {
    def apply(start: DateTime, end: DateTime) = new org.joda.time.Interval(start, end)
    def unapply(interval: org.joda.time.Interval) = Some((interval.getStart, interval.getEnd))
  }
}
```

so the code of the OP compiles as is only missing the `import IntervalUtils._` and then as added bonus can also do:

```
implicit val jodaIntervalWrites = new Writes[org.joda.time.Interval] {
  def writes(interval: org.joda.time.Interval) = Json.obj(
    "start" -> interval.getStart,
    "end" -> interval.getEnd
  )
}

implicit val jodaIntervalReads: Reads[org.joda.time.Interval] = (
    (JsPath \ "start").read[DateTime] and
    (JsPath \ "end").read[DateTime]
  )(Interval.apply _) // <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< reused here
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To do this, you don't need a case class, you just need two methods with suitable signatures, and you can define them easily:

```
object JodaTime {
  def mkInterval(start: ReadableInstant, end: ReadableInstant) = new Interval(start, end)
  def unmkInterval(interval: Interval) = Some((interval.getStart, interval.getEnd))
}

// elsewhere
mapping(
  "start" -> jodaDate,
  "end" -> jodaDate,
)(JodaTime.mkInterval)(JodaTime.unmkInterval)
```

In fact, you don't even need `mkInterval`, you can just write `new Interval(_, _)` (not sure if overloads can cause a problem for this specific use-case, but if so just specify the placeholder types).

Answer (score 1):

One solution could be to create an implicit class with the apply and unapply (and others you may desire like the copy) methods, simulating a case class: http://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/core/implicit-classes.html